# Qualtrics Suvrveys - Pipe text the variable name selected

Tags: qualtrics

I am able to display the selected response but not the variable name given to the response. I am not able to find an option in qualtrics that lets you pipe in the variable name given to a response. Has anyone done this before?

For example, I have a survey of 15 Yes or no questions. For some questions, "Yes" is a favorable answer and for some "No" is the favorable answer. To avoid confusions in the final report, i have added a variable name to the responses as favorable response and unfavorable response. At the end of each survey, I have added a summary page that shows the responses chosen so far in a table. To add better clarity, I would like to display the responses selected in this summary page as the variable name selected i.e, "favorable" or "unfavorable" rather than "Yes" or "No".

Is there a way to pipe text the variable name selected in Qualtrics? Please advise.

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean by "variable name".

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you want to pipe the embedded data variable name rather than value? I'm not sure I can think of a use case for this...

Comment: @AnthonyRivas: I have added an example of the use case.

Comment: @T.Gibbons : When you enter the frame to assign re-code values, there are 2 options. Assign a re-code value and/or a variable name. This is what i am referring to as variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification. No, there is no way to pipe the recode variable names.

You can assign embedded data variables corresponding to each question with the values "favorable" or "unfavorable" in the survey flow using branches.